# Проблема с отображением прозрачности GIF в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме есть много динамически создающихся PictureBox. Все они являются дочерними элементами управления для некоторого Panel. У изображений, которые я желаю отображать, присутствует альфа канал. Проблема в том, что альфа канал интерпретируется неправильно.

Установка свойства `BackColor` не помогает: PictureBox'ы принадлежат Panel, а значит и задний фон - белая панель.

В интернете нашел сдеюущий способ, но он не работает (изображение не отображается):

```
public class PictureBoxTW : PictureBox
    {
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        // Paint background with underlying graphics from other controls
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            if (Parent != null)
            {
                // Take each control in turn
                int index = Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(this);
                for (int i = Parent.Controls.Count - 1; i > index; i--)
                {
                    Control c = Parent.Controls[i];

                    // Check it's visible and overlaps this control
                    if (c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Bounds) && c.Visible)
                    {
                        // Load appearance of underlying control and redraw it on this background
                        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, g);
                        c.DrawToBitmap(bmp, c.ClientRectangle);
                        g.TranslateTransform(c.Left - Left, c.Top - Top);
                        g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, Point.Empty);
                        g.TranslateTransform(Left - c.Left, Top - c.Top);
                        bmp.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

У кого-нибудь найдется готовый способ решения этой проблемы, для которого мне не потребуются танцы с бубном?

Comment: Есть один железобетонный способ решить все проблемы с прозрачностью - WPF. А так, у вас возможно включена двойная буферизация на форме, попробуйте ради эксперимента выключить. Если не включена, значит я просто не угадал.

Comment: Двойная буферизация в обоих состояниях никак не повлияла на результат.

Comment: согласен с aepot - винформс протсто не предназначен для отрисовки нормального юая с прозрачностями и другими эфектами. Хочешь плюшки - переходи на WPF. Это самое верное и самое простое(в долгострочной перспективе) решение.

Comment: Вот тут не помешали бы пара скриншотов: как сейчас выводится и как хотелось бы получить изображение.

Comment: Например, полностью черный квадрат и красный круг, вторая половинка которого полностью прозрачна. При таком порядке добавления я не вижу на прозрачной половинке круга черного: я вижу белый фон Panel. Код я уже знатно перекроил, а изображений не сделал - мой косяк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Косо да ломо решил проблему, но мне пришлось отказаться от любых PictureBox, принять факт двойной буферизации и рисовать прямо на форме. Далее следуют рабочие обрывки из класса реализации.

```
class TransparentPictureBox {

public bool            require_paint { get; private set; }
public Action<Effect>  force_paint   { get; private set; }
private Bitmap frame;

public TransparentPictureBox (string file, Action<TransparentPictureBox> force_paint) {
    this.frame       = new Bitmap(file);
    this.force_paint = force_paint;

    OnShow();
}

/**
 * @brief Обрабатывает событие рисования.
 * @details
 * Отрисовывает текущий кадр эффекта поверх всего остального.
 * Вызывающий должен самостоятельно обрабатывать порядок отрисовки
 * 
 * @param e Аргументы события для отрисовки.
 */
public void Paint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    require_paint = false;
    ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(frame, new Point(0, 0));
}

private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    require_paint = true;
    force_paint(this);
}

/// @brief Сохранение состояния перед скрытием.
public void OnHide() {
    require_paint = true;
    force_paint(this);
    ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(frame, new EventHandler(OnFrameChanged));
}

/// @brief Возобновление состояния перед появлением.
public void OnShow() {
    ImageAnimator.Animate(frame, new EventHandler(OnFrameChanged));
    require_paint = true;
    force_paint(this);
}

}
```

То есть я рисую на форме абсолютно все объекты TransparentPictureBox каждый раз, когда меняется кадр анимации любого из них.

Не думаю, что мне это понравится. Этот способ имеет множество недостатков и требует большого (боль какого) внешнего управления.